# Flash CS5 "Value is not a function"

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am trying to work with variables to have a few rollovers do what I want. I wrote the first one to test it out and it decided it hated me. the code is as follows:

```
var currentPetal = "Intro";
var playmc = currentPetal + "Text";

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,firstplay);
function firstplay(event:Event) {
    IntroText.gotoAndPlay(2); 
}

Petal1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,puretextover);
function puretextover(event:MouseEvent):void {
    playmc = currentPetal+"Text";
    playmc.gotoAndPlay(21);
    currentPetal="Pure";
    PureText.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

It keeps telling me when i roll over the object that my function isn't really a function .. any ideas on why it's doing that?

```
TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.
    at Flower_fla::MainTimeline/puretextover()
```

I have placed all this on a layer of its own in the first frame of the main timeline. It is a one frame movie with other MC's placed on t

Thanks,

Silver Tiger

Answer (score 2):

you can't do playmc.gotoAndPlay(21);

because playmc is a string, not a movieclip